# Java math issue

Tags: eclipse, math.sqrt

Can any one tell me how to write this type of code in eclipse propject. basically i want to square root the samv and samvi variables. i am getting syntax  error.

```
int ki, l,;   
 int samv = (tdrum / k) / l;
 int samvi = (tdrum / ki) / l;

int samv2 =  (Math.sqrt(samv);
int samv2i =  (Math.sqrt(samvi);
```

Comment: int ki, l; don't forget to initial ki and l first.

Answer (score 4):

Many Error extra *commas* less *brackets*

```
int ki, l;   
 int samv = (tdrum / k) / l;
 int samvi = (tdrum / ki) / l;

int samv2 =  (Math.sqrt(samv));
int samv2i =  (Math.sqrt(samvi));
```

Answer (score 2):

Take care of the brackets. And use a double because sqrt() returns no int:

```
double samv2 =  Math.sqrt(samv);
double samv2i =  Math.sqrt(samvi);
```